# How to get PyTest fixtures to autocomplete in PyCharm (type hinting)

Tags: pytest

I had a bear of a time figuring this out, and it was really bugging me, so I thought I'd post this here in case anyone hit the same problem...

(and the answer is so dang simple it hurts :-)

**The Problem**

The core of the issue is that sometimes, not always, when dealing with fixtures in PyTest that return objects, when you use those fixtures in a test in PyCharm, you don't get autocomplete hints. If you have objects with large numbers of methods you want to reference while writing a test, this can add a lot of overhead and inconvenience to the test writing process.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the issue:

Let's say I've got a class "event_manager" that lives in:

```
location.game.events
```

Let's further say that in my conftest.py file (PyTest standard thing for the unfamiliar), I've got a fixture that returns an instance of that class:

```
from location.game.events import event_manager

...

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def event_mgr():
    """Creates a new instance of event generate for use in tests"""
    return event_manager()
```

I've had issues sometimes, (but not always - I can't quite figure out why) with classes like this where autocomplete will not work properly in the test code where I use the fixture, e.g.

```
def test_tc10657(self, evt_mgr):
    """Generates a Regmod and expects filemod to be searchable on server"""
    evt_mgr.(This does not offer autocomplete hints when you type ".")
```

So the answer is actually quite simple, once you review type hinting in PyCharm:
http://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

Here's how to fix the above test code so that autocomplete works properly:

```
from location.game.events import event_manager 

...

def test_tc10657(self, evt_mgr: event_manager):
    """Generates a Regmod and expects filemod to be searchable on server"""
    evt_mgr.(This DOES offer hints when you type "." Yay!)
```

Notice how I explicitly type the fixture as an input parameter of type event_manager.

Comment: From what I can tell, as of 2016.2, PyCharm is largely ignorant of a number of features particular to pytest. Inspections complain of shadowing names of fixtures defined in the same file, no autocompletion from fixture names, etc. Thanks for the suggestion though--it'll help until there is better support.

Comment: How would go about this with Python 2.7? I tried following the jetbrains.com link where it suggests using stub files but I can't seem to get it to work. In my case I'm doing `from selenium import webdriver` and I have a fixture that yields a PhantomJS browser and then on my individual tests I can't get auto-suggestions for the driver object.

Comment: I think the point is how to make this happen without type annotation in your test parameters. Still useful this way but it feels unnecessary to repeat it for each testcase.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you add a docstring to a function and specify the type of the the parameters, you will get the code completion for those parameters.

**For example using pytest and Selenium:**

```py
# The remote webdriver seems to be the base class for the other webdrivers
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

def test_url(url, browser_driver):
    """
    This method is used to see if IBM is in the URL title
    :param  WebDriver browser_driver: The browser's driver
    :param str url: the URL to test
    """
    browser_driver.get(url)
    assert "IBM" in browser_driver.title
```

**Here's my conftest.py file as well**

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

# Method to handle the command line arguments for pytest
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--driver", action="store", default="chrome", help="Type in browser type")
    parser.addoption("--url", action="store", default='https://www.ibm.com', help="url")


@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def browser_driver(request):
    browser = request.config.getoption("--driver").lower()
    # yield the driver to the specified browser
    if browser == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
    else:
        raise Exception("No driver for browser " + browser)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def url(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--url")
```

Tested using Python 2.7 and PyCharm 2017.1. The docstring format is reStructuredText and the "Analyze Python code in docstrings" checkbox is checked in settings.